# How to kill all Greenlets or end "While not Queue.empty()" loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, queue, gevent

How to end Gevent without using sys.exit() in this case?
I don't need to finish all the elements in the list, I just need to use the queue until a string is found.

```
tasks = Queue()
while not tasks.empty():
            string = tasks.get()
            con = validate(string)
            if con == True:
                break
```

Break statement is not working.
I am starting the Greenlets like this:

```
gevent.spawn(worker)
```

I cant use sys.exit() for the reason that I want to iterate though a list and start a new Gevent instance for every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with python, but try using a boolean as an extra condition for your while loop:

```
tasks = Queue()
found = False
while not found and not tasks.empty():
    string = tasks.get()
    found = validate(string)
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats indeed the solution to break out of the loop. I am still looking for a solution how to stop the other greenlets though.